# Deactivating viber

Tags: viber-messenger

I have Viber on my cellphone(Android) and on my desktop with same number.I lent my laptop to my friend and forgot to delete Viber from my desktop.Now I want to deactivate it from desktop but my laptop is not accessible. How can I do it by remote. give me a solution please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating your Viber account from your phone will deactivate it from all of your devices.
You can find the instructions on the official site [here](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1335420-deactivate-your-viber-account-mobile-#.VOstwOPogqE).

As given in the site,

> Viber -> More Options -> Settings -> Privacy -> Deactivate Account